# How to get and show additional options from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a nested JSON file that has a few products in it. I'm trying to build a product selection tool. See the JSON file here: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5b1f5423310000570023077f

What I'm trying to do is "drill down" or show all the options for each of the products when clicked. So each product has 2 variations. Item 1 has 2 options. Item 2 has 3 options. I just want to show each of the respective items options when I click on their names.

Here's a demo of what I have so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/kZsOjjFaEZDKCGGiBYFS?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="rac" ng-controller="prodCtrl">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="prodCtrl">
    <h3>Please choose a product</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="product in products">
        <a href ng-click='setSelectedProduct(product)'>{{product.name}}</a> 
 </li>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <!-- This section will automatically display detail when selectedProduct is updated -->
   <div class="detail">
       <div class="detailimagewrapper">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="product in setSelectedProduct(product)">
              <a href ng-click='setSelectedProduct(product)'> 
  {{product.name}}</a></li>
             </li>
            </ul>
             <img class="detailimage" src="{{product.image}}" >
          </div>
         <p>{{selectedProduct.description}}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Order Now</a>
       </div>

      </div>

    </div>
   </div>
```

Here's my JS:

```js
var rac = angular.module('rac', ['angular.filter']);

rac.controller('prodCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce, $filter) {
  $http.jsonp($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(
      "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5b1f5423310000570023077f"), {
      jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data.data.products;
      },
      function(error) {});
  $scope.setSelectedProduct = function($scope) {
    console.log($scope);
    if ($scope.options.image) {
      $scope.selectedProductImage = product.options.image;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: You have quite a few problems which aren't going to be fixed with an answer here. The main thing is your json is returning two different objects, so an `ng-repeat` on the options won't work because the options list is different. Also, your html and javascript don't match at all. You are referencing `product.image` in html but `$scope.options.image` in the js, yet you never declared `$scope.options`, so this will always be false. You never set `selectedProduct`. I think if you clean this up, you will get more help, I for one would be willing to help.

Comment: I appreciate that Tyler. I'm still learning.  Very beginning stages, so I apologize. Thank you for the direction though. It's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly messy, but I think what you want is nested `ng-repeat`, that access the data after one product was selected. I decided not to make it pretty and just pull it out as is. For that I used two `ng-repeat`, one for selected options, the other is for the key and values of the objects.

Here is a demo:

```js
var rac = angular.module('rac', ['angular.filter']);

rac.controller('prodCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce, $filter) {
  $http.jsonp($sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5b1f5423310000570023077f"), {
      jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data.data.products;
      },
      function(error) {}
    );
  $scope.selected = null;
  $scope.setSelectedProduct = function(product) {
    $scope.selected = product;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.17/angular-filter.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="rac" ng-controller="prodCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div ng-controller="prodCtrl">
        <h3>Please choose a product</h3>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="product in products">
            <a href ng-click='setSelectedProduct(product)'>
              {{product.name}}
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <!-- This section will automatically display detail when selectedProduct is updated -->
        <div class="detail">
          <div class="detailimagewrapper">
            <ul ng-repeat="s in selected.options">
              <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in s">
                <!-- Make this as pretty as you want -->
                <span ng-if="key!='image'">{{key}}: {{value}}</span>
                <span ng-if="key=='image'"><img style="width:100px" ng-src="{{value}}"></span>
              </li>
              <hr>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are more patient than I am.

Comment: This is very helpful Aleksey. I hope this sets me in the right direction. Let me try it out